# Object Design constructors vs setter methods

Tags: api, oop

Hey I have a generic question about Object Oriented Design programming, specifically about creating objects/interfaces that eventually become API's and extensible frameworks that programmers then use. Lets say I am creating an object called "Shoe" that has some private data variables such as "brand", "type", "gender", "size", "color", and "brand_id"

Now lets say a programmer wants to create a Shoe object. How would I then go about achieving a way for a programmer to set the Shoe classes private data variables. Should I create a long-winded constructor such as "Shoe(string brand, String type, int size, Color c, int id)"

Or should I make the Shoe constructor simple, such as "Shoe()" and then provide setter methods for all of these private data variables such as setBrand(), setType(), and etc.

The problem with setter methods is that if I pass this object over to a third party client or even another function, the programmer then has the ability set/overwrite the values of these data variables rendering the newly created shoe object useless. If someone wanted to pass in an Addidas shoe, now a programmer can re-write the object to be Nike and store it. What is the best answer/solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "best solution" for this issue.

IMHO you should undestrand which behaviours (methods) are fundamental for your "shoes" and put them in your interface. For example:

```
public interface Shoe{
    int getSize();
    void wear();
}
```

Setter, getters, contructor and object state in general are implementing details for your concrete classes, not for the interface. Concrete classes can be designed in several ways, so you don't need to worry about that.

Setters and getters must be put in the interface only if they are an imprescindible behaviour for the entity represented by your interface, otherwise you should avoid them.